# LISP Replace elements in one list with elements of another list according to the value of each element in the first list

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I have two lists.
L1 = '(( 8 6 8 7 8 8 ) (  8 7  7 6 8 7))

L2 = '( (P (Q R)) (Q (P U)) (R( T Q S)) (S (R U Q)) (T( P Q )) (U( R P)) )

For every element in L2, I want to replace it with the appropriate element in the list of L1.

Every P in L2 should be replaced by the 1st element of each sublist in L1

Every Q in L2 should be replaced by the 2nd element of each sublist in L1

Every R in L2 should be replaced by the 3rd element of each sublist in L1

Every S in L2 should be replaced by the 4th element of each sublist in L1

Every T in L2 should be replaced by the 5th element of each sublist in L1

Every U in L2 should be replaced by the 6th element of each sublist in L1

According to the first sublist, the resultant L2 is '(( 8 ( 6 7)) ( 6 ( 8 8)) (8 (8 6 7)) (7 (8 8 6)) (8 ( 8 6)) (6( 8 8))

```
 setq L1  '(( 8 6 8 7 8 8 ) (  8 7  7 6 8 7))
 setq L2  '( (P (Q R)) (Q (P U)) (R( T Q S)) (S (R U Q)) (T( P Q ) (U( R P)) )
(dolist(ele L1)
 (dolist(ele2 L2)
  (progn (substitute (nth 0 L1) 'p ele2)(substitute (nth 1 L1) 'q ele2)
  (substitute (nth 0 L1) 'r ele2)(substitute (nth 0 L1) 's ele2)
  (substitute (nth 0 L1) 't ele2)(substitute (nth 0 L1) 'u ele2))))
```

Thank you

Comment: Your code What do you mean by "Nth element of each sublist in L1"? What result should be if we run such subtstitution on `'(q q q) '((1 2 3) (4 5 6))`? Don't use T for anything but true value. Note, that substitute returns a new list, not modifies passed one, so your code can't work as you expecting.

Comment: Is that supposed to be `(t (p q))` in L2?  As written, I don't think your parentheses are balanced.

Comment: Yes joushua, you are right!

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor, I like complete absence of parenthesis around `setq` much more. @kirk, you need no fix that `(t (p q))` thing in your code too.

Comment: @Mark yes, `setq x y` is a nice touch.  As I recall, some REPLs actually will allow you to omit outermost parenthesis.  I don't expect people use that functionality much, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure about your example, but this might get you started:

```
(defun f (mapvals sxp)
  (let ((mapping nil)) 
    (labels
        ((sub (sxp) ; local function - recursive tree traversal
           (cond
            ((null sxp)  nil)
            ((consp sxp) (cons (sub (car sxp)) (sub (cdr sxp))))
            (t                  ; we have an atom, so let's replace it
             (let ((val (assoc sxp mapping))) ; look up the mapping of the atom
               (if val          ; mapping exists?
                   (cdr val)    ; yes, use associated value
                   (let ((newval (pop mapvals)))  ; no, pop next value from mapvals
                     (setf mapping (cons (cons sxp newval) mapping)) ; and remember mapping
                     newval)))))))
      (sub sxp))))
```

Testing:

```
? (f '(1 2 3 4 5 6)
     '((P (Q R)) (Q (P U)) (R (T Q S)) (S (R U Q)) (T (P Q)) (U (R P))))
((1 (2 3)) (2 (1 4)) (3 (5 2 6)) (6 (3 4 2)) (5 (1 2)) (4 (3 1)))
```